# Moving piece across a board in Haskell

Tags: haskell, global-variables, monads

I'm working on a chess game in Haskell and I'm struggling with moving my pieces.

I understand that in functional programming, everything should be immutable, but I think I really need to have an updated list of pieces. I looked at `monad.state` but I'm having a hard time understanding it.

This is my list of pieces :

```
piecesList::[Piece]
piecesList = [Piece _type _color _coords, ..., ... Piece _type _color _coords]
```

And my approach for moving a piece from `(old_x,old_y)` to `(new_x,new_y)`:

- find the piece with `(old_x,old_y)` as coordinates in my list:

  ```
  piece = getPiece (index_of (old_x old_y))
  ```

  with

  ```
  getPiece::Int->Piece
  getPiece a = piecesList!!a
  ```

  and

  ```
  index_of :: (Int,Int)->Int
  index_of (old_x, old_y)  = fromJust $ findIndex piece piecesList
    where
      piece (Piece _ _ pos) = pos == (old_x, old_y)
  ```
- update the coordinates of this particular piece:

  ```
  moved = move (piece (new_x,new_y))
  ```

  with

  ```
  move::Piece->(Int,Int)->Piece
  move piece (new_x,new_y) = piece { _position = (new_x,new_y) }
  ```
- update the list of pieces with:

  ```
  piecesList = updateBoard (index_of a b ) moved
  ```

  with

  ```
  updateBoard :: Int -> Piece -> Maybe [Piece]
  updateBoard index newPiece = return board
    where
      (x,_:ys) = splitAt index piecesList
      board = x ++ newPiece : ys
  ```

But still, it looks like my list of pieces is not updated.

Am I close to it? If so, what am I missing? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I'm using the following types:

```
data Piece = Piece {
  _type :: PieceType,
  _color :: PieceColor,
  _position :: Position
} deriving Eq

data PieceColor = Black | White deriving Eq
data PieceType = Rook | Knight | Bishop | King | Queen | Pawn deriving Eq
type Position = (Int, Int)
```

Comment: Please always first introduce the types you use (i.e., `data Piece = ...`), in a question like this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout done sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Ok. Well, I see the definition isn't actually that relevant to the question here, but in general it's annoying to see some data constructor expressions and having no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it looks like my list of pieces is not updated.

Of course not: like everything in Haskell, the list of pieces is *immutable*, so it will never change under any circumstances.

With

```
piecesList = updateBoard (index_of a b ) moved
```

you merely define a *new* list of pieces, which also happens to be called `pieces`. GHCi and IHaskell allow this kind of *shadowing* (Haskell itself does not!), but it simply means that anything you define *afterwards* which refers to `piecesList` will use the new version. But `getPiece` and `index_of` already have already been defined before this “update”, and are completely oblivious to any new definitions you choose to come up with later on.

The most directly way to accomplish a task like this is to explicitly pass *a modified version* of the game state around. In fact `updateBoard` already goes that direction by giving an entire `[Piece]` list as the result. But you also need to *use* that updated state in the next step, rather than again the start state `piecesList`. Basically, if you just pass `pieces` as an *argument* to `getPiece`, `index_of` and `updateBoard`, you'll get the task done.

```
updateBoard :: Int -> Piece -> [Piece] -> [Piece] -- You don't seem to need `Maybe`
```

Note that this signature is parsed as

```
updateBoard :: Int -> Piece -> ([Piece] -> [Piece])
```

Now, it's a bit awkward, having to explicitly give the same old value to all kinds of helper functions. You already mention the *state monad*, which is indeed the standard thing to use here. Essentially, the state monad does the exact same thing: passing a value around as an argument to sub-functions. The only difference is that, if not told otherwise, it *automatically uses always the same value*.

You change the signature to

```
import Control.Monad.State
updateBoard :: Int -> Piece -> State [Piece] ()
```

Here, `State [Piece] ()` is just a newtype wrapper for `[Piece] -> ([Piece], ())`. The `()` says that you don't give any interesting result information apart from the updated state. You *could* give other information too, and indeed need to in `getPieces` and `indexOf`:

```
getPiece :: Int -> State [Piece] Piece
indexOf :: (Int,Int) -> State [Piece] Int
```

Now as to how everything is actually written: `do` notation helps. Simply put the result in a `return` at the end, and obtain the old state with `get`. For example,

```
getPiece :: Int -> State [Piece] Piece
getPiece a = do
   piecesList <- get
   return $ piecesList!!a
```

The new state can simply be “`put` into the monad”:

```
updateBoard :: Int -> Piece -> State [Piece] ()
updateBoard index newPiece = do
    piecesList <- get
    let (x,_:ys) = splitAt index piecesList
    put $ x ++ newPiece : ys
```

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. I understand that it is a scope issue. My problem is that `index_of`, as well as other functions using `piecesList` like `piece_exist` or `move_is_valid` are also used in a c++ part of this program (for the GUI) using `foreign export ccall`.
So is there any way to declare `piecesList` as global (mutable). I understand that this is surely not the Haskell way though.

Comment: If you are mixing OO and functional programming without a clear understanding of both then you are going to find it difficult. The usual solution here is to put all the C++ external calls into the IO monad, along with the structures they mutate. Your Haskell program gets a pointer to a structure, but any access to it is via an IO function. However this pushes your entire program into the IO monad. As you say, this is not the Haskell way. See gtk2hs for a large library written this way.

Comment: @MaximeVAST this kind of language-interoperation is much more tricky than writing it all in pure Haskell alone. It can be done, but I strongly recommend you first learn Haskell itself thoroughly.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I understand what both of you you are saying. My goal (and what I have achieved so far) is to have a c++ program displaying/moving the pieces and catching user inputs (using sfml) and two "backends"  (one in c++ and one in haskell) checking the validity of the movements and the respect of the rules. My first "backend" in c++ is done, as well as the GUI. My haskell "backend" still need to return the validity of a movement to c++. So if I may insist, is there a way of making the piecesList mutable/global ? (because I don't want to write the GUI in haskell) Thank you for your time.

Comment: The Haskell backend doesn't need to know anything about the global mutable nature of anything you do in the C++ part. Just call the Haskell backend as a pure function, which accepts the current state and returns whatever information you're interested in (possibly including some updated state).

Comment: Regarding your insist: no, it is not possible to make `piecesList` mutable. What is possible however is to write an `IO` _action_ `getPiecesList` (this is actually similar to the `get` method of the `state` monad that I wrote about) which always requests the current state from the mutable C++ variable when you ask it. But as Paul said, this pushes you _entire_ backend into the `IO` monad, which is rather ridiculous since, after the getting-the-current-state bit it's a perfectly good pure function.

Comment: That's the point; I'm only displaying stuff with c++. The pieces are moving in the Haskell part. Let me be more specific: This is a uni assignment. The subject was: 1) write a game in c++ (with a GUI). 2) write the same (standalone) game in Haskell (without a GUI). I have done both. Having a single common GUI for both program is just a 'bonus' that I want to add. 
So the list containing the pieces is in Haskell, not in c++.

Comment: So you're basically just using the C++ part as a specialised widget toolkit for a GUI game written in Haskell. In that case, you _must_ have some `IO` in the Haskell part (otherwise it won't be able to call the impure C++ code). This isn't too difficult, but it's rather a different question from the one you originally asked, so I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: One last precision (because I understand that this is not easy to help me in the comment section), it is the c++ that call Haskell functions, not the other way. (c++ catch user input (e.g. move e2 to e4); c++ asks Haskell if "e2e4" is a valid move; if so, haskell internally move e2 to e4 and c++ display it).

I've just seen that you edited your answer. I'm going to accept it and try to work with Monad. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141290/discussion-between-maxime-vast-and-leftaroundabout).

Comment: Ugh, that doesn't sound like a good division. No matter which language it is written in, the one doing the calling should also handle the state, or at least have a grasp of where that state is encapsulated. Even if writing it _all_ in C++, it's bad project design to have a function with global / local-static state that's not evident to the caller. This leads to various maintenance issues, not to speak of deadlocks once you make it multithreaded.